# How To Add ImageTools GIF To Grid in Windows Phone 8 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am making a program that will use the Windows Phone 8 Silverlight

I want to Show GIF Image with ImageTools on Grid but I can't add ExtendedImage grid's children.

```
Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();
ExtendedImage eAt = new ExtendedImage();
eAt.UriSource = new Uri("medias/at.gif", UriKind.Relative);
grd.Children.Add(eAt);
```

Error : `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ImageTools.ExtendedImage' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'`

I'll be glad if you fix it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use Image like this:

```
Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();
ExtendedImage eAt = new ExtendedImage();
eAt.UriSource = new Uri(@"/medias/at.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
eAt.LoadingCompleted += new EventHandler((ss, ee) =>
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = eAt.ToBitmap();
        grd.Children.Add(img);
    });
});
```

Comment: When I wrote that type I gave an error
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PhoneCodeContractsAssemblies.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Image has not been loaded.

Comment: Thank you for everything it worked but gif image didn't animated. Image is stopping like jpg or png image

Comment: If my answer helped you, you should upvote my answer. However, you did not ask for help with AnimatedImage so it is understandable the animation don't start (e.g. the eAt.ToBitmap() call).

Comment: I can't vote up. when I earned reputation points I am going to vote up :) Thank you for everything.